# PHP continuous include

Tags: php

I tried many way to solve this, but it's still not working.

OS : debian wheezy
I'm running in php5.4.4

I've a file tester.php which includes test1.php and the test1 includes test2.php.

I only can use include_once `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test2/test2.php";` in test1.php

I cannot use `include_once "../test2/test2.php";` could everybody tell me why?

Error Message:

> ```
> Warning: include_once(../test2/test2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/test1/test1.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../test2/test2.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/test1/test1.php on line 2
> ```

tester.php

```
<?php
    include_once "test1/test1.php";
    echo "tester";
?>
```

test1.php

```
<?php
    include_once "../test2/test2.php";
    echo "test1";
?>
```

test2.php

```
<?php
    echo "test2";
?>
```

Structure:

```
 +-test1/
 |  |    
 |  +---- test1.php
 |
 +-test2/
 |  |
 |  +---- test2.php
 |
 --tester.php
```

can any body tell me how to fix this question?
Many thanks.

Comment: Paths are relative to the invocation script (`tester.php`), not the currently included script. In your `test1.php` the current working directory is still the DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: @mario thanks but why paths are relative to the invocation script ,in my to my mind is cannot to be this is what i setting somethings to change that??

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

include(dirname(**FILE**).'/test.php');

**or**

```
define('PATH','/home/devp/public_html/project/includes');
include(PATH.'/test.php');
```

Comment: Hello @Anil R thanks for your answer ! 
I konw other to solve but i just want to know why?????
why i cannot direct use ../ to point to test2.php @@

Comment: It's a good practice to include file using absolute path rather than relative path. If you are using same files in main folder and sub folders the relative path can cause issue.

Comment: I don't get why people still think `include` needs parenthesis. BTW you don't like `__DIR__`, do you?

Comment: i try to put the tester.php from / to /tester folder but still cannot fix the issue ? Do i setting something lead to this question happen?

Comment: @Markus Malkusch i am like to use __DIR__ or other function but i just want to know why.

Comment: It's 2014, use `__DIR__`, not `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are call `include_once './../test2/test2.php';`, this basically tells to go out one folder, and open `test2.php` in `/test2/`

If you want to include `test2.php` from for example `tester.php`, the path would be: `./test2/test2.php`

**Note:** `./` means relative to the current path, you don't need it but just a preference.

Comment: First thanks for your helping but my question is in when test1.php include by tester i cannot use test1.php to include relative path file! but in my php5.4 or older version this is working fine . I just want to konw what didi I done so this issue happen.  Or this question is normal.

Comment: Yse I only can use include_once '/test2/test2.php' in test1.php cannot use include_once '../test2/test2.php'